# ASP.NET MVC How do I point a controller action to a different view?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-2

I have a controller with a method that points to a view.  How do I change the view that the action is mapped to?  Like I want it to call ViewB instead of ViewA? Where do these mappings exist and how can I modify them? Thanks for any tips.

Thanks,
~ck in San Diego

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Instead of:

```
return View(someModel);
```

use

```
return View("ViewYouWant", someModel);
```

Answer (score 7):

To have a controller method redirect to a view that's not named the same as the action method, you can change the statement from

```
 return View();
```

to

```
 return View("ViewB");
```

Answer (score 2):

You could also return a `RedirectToAction("View")`, or with Javascript

```
 json(new { Redirect = url.Action(action, data) }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

and handle the return appropriately on the client side.

Happy Hunting!

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the view name into the `View` method: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.view.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You can do the default:

```
return View(myModel);
```

Or specify the View Name under the same controller view folders or in shared:

```
return View("ThatView", myModel);
```

Or whatever view:

```
return View("~/myfolder/WhatEverView.ascx", myModel);
```